# Google Indexing API - Invalid attribute. 'url' is not in standard URL format - But my URL is Correct

Tags: python, google-indexing-api

I am currently using Indexing API v3.

When I am using this API in a loop, I got this error:

Invalid attribute. 'url' is not in standard URL format

But I am pretty sure that my URL is correct, because it is download from Google search console:

Here is the code:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2
import json

import pandas as pd

JSON_KEY_FILE = "key.json"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

# This file contains 2 column, URL and date
csv = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
csv[["URL"]][0:10].apply(lambda x: indexURL(x.to_string(), http), axis=1)

def indexURL(url, http):

    ENDPOINT = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"

    content = {}
    content['url'] = url
    content['type'] = "URL_UPDATED"
    json_ctn = json.dumps(content)

    response, content = http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=json_ctn)

    result = json.loads(content.decode())

    if("error" in result):
        print("Error({} - {}): {}".format(result["error"]["code"], result["error"]["status"], result["error"]["message"]))
    else:
        print("urlNotificationMetadata.url: {}".format(result["urlNotificationMetadata"]["url"]))
        print("urlNotificationMetadata.latestUpdate.url: {}".format(result["urlNotificationMetadata"]["latestUpdate"]["url"]))
        print("urlNotificationMetadata.latestUpdate.type: {}".format(result["urlNotificationMetadata"]["latestUpdate"]["type"]))
        print("urlNotificationMetadata.latestUpdate.notifyTime: {}".format(result["urlNotificationMetadata"]["latestUpdate"]["notifyTime"]))
```

Here is a list of URL sample:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that even if I apply `.strip()` to each row, there is still a `\n` at the end of each URL.

So instead of putting row one by one to lambda, I put the whole series to lambda and use a for-loop to handle it.

The whole working example is here:

[Google Indexing API v3 Working Example with Python 3](https://gist.github.com/alucard001/fedce21b80a3de7aa3c07299838e1462)